# Understanding hybrid arguments in detail

Tags: provable-security, distinguisher

Assume we are given three distributions $H_{1}$, $H_{2}$ and $H_{3}$ and the following security games:

- $Game_{1}$: Distinguish between $H_{1}$ and $H_{3}$.
- $Game_{2}$: Distinguish between $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$.
- $Game_{3}$: Distinguish between $H_{2}$ and $H_{3}$.

I am trying to prove that for every adversary A, $Adv_{Game_{1}}(A)\leq Adv_{Game_{2}}(A)+Adv_{Game_{3}}(A)$.

Starting the proof, from the definition of the advantage, $Adv_{Game_{1}}(A)=|\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{1}|H_{1})-\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{3}|H_{1})|=|\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{1}|H_{1})-|Pr(A$ guesses $H_{2}|H_{1})+\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{2}|H_{1})-\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{3}|H_{1})|$.

The problem is that when I attempt to use the triangle inequality, I will need to be able to write $\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{3}|H_{2})$ in terms of $\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{3}|H_{1})$ and also $\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{2}|H_{1})$ in terms of $\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{2}|H_{2})$. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What do all those / mean?

Comment: Just the conditional probability, I should have used | instead. $\Pr(A$ guesses $H_{3}|H_{1})$ is just the probability that when A is given an element a in $H_{1}$, A guesses that a is drawn from $H_{3}$.

Comment: I recommend starting by showing equivalence to the definition in which the adversary's output space is {0,1}. ​ ​

Comment: This is what happens above anyway. In each game the challenger draws uniformly at random a bit $b\leftarrow \{0,1\}$ and then samples element $a$ either according to the left or to the right distribution.

Comment: Well, your question indicates something different from what I described. ​ ​

Comment: See V. Shoup. Sequences of games: A tool for taming complexity in security proofs.  Available from http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/332/, 2004.